# Draw vector drawable on canvas (image stretched)

Tags: android, pdf, canvas, pdf-generation

I am creating pdf using PDF api provided in android,i want to draw `image` in pdf at specific `x,y`.

drawing done but because of small size the vactore drawable get streached and producing low quality output.

Here the code that i am using to draw drawable.

```
    Drawable starIcon = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star);
    VectorDrawableCompat moonIcon = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.ic_moon,getActivity().getTheme());

    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 2).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    float x = drawX + (perItemWidth * col);
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    rectF.set(x + 2.5F - perItemWidth, drawY + 1, x + 1, drawY + perItemHeight - 1);

    float importantSpaceFromLeft = (rectF.width() * 10F) / 100F;
    float importantSpaceFromTop = ((rectF.height() * 2F) / 100F);

    Rect moonIconBounds = new Rect();
    moonIconBounds.left = (int) (rectF.left + ((rectF.height() * 10F) / 100F)) + 10;
    moonIconBounds.right = (int) (rectF.left + ((rectF.height() * 10F) / 100F)) + 20;
    moonIconBounds.bottom = (int) (rectF.bottom - importantSpaceFromTop) - 10 - 2;
    moonIconBounds.top = (int) (rectF.bottom - importantSpaceFromTop) - 20 - 2;

    //Setting bounds like 0,0,20,20
    moonIcon.setBounds(0,0,moonIconBounds.width(),moonIconBounds.height());
    canvas.save();
    //Translate canvas to draw at x,y
    canvas.translate(moonIconBounds.left,moonIconBounds.top);
    moonIcon.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    Rect starIconBounds = new Rect();
    starIconBounds.left = (int) (rectF.left + ((rectF.height() * 10F) / 100F)) + 10;
    starIconBounds.right = (int) (rectF.left + ((rectF.height() * 10F) / 100F)) + 20;
    starIconBounds.bottom = (int) (rectF.bottom - importantSpaceFromTop);
    starIconBounds.top = (int) (rectF.bottom - importantSpaceFromTop) - 10;

    //Setting bound from rect
    starIcon.setBounds(starIconBounds);
    starIcon.draw(canvas);
```

**`output`**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Alh.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4kce.png]

Both image producing same result drawbles are streatching, i don't know why both of vectors are converted from **svg**.
How can i achive batter results.